# How to earn the Tag Editor badge on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

In my available badges there is one badge(Tag Editor). How to earn this badge.

[image]

&

What is the use of tag editing because the creator will give all details and then it will be peer reviewed, and then only it is visible to the public.

Will tag editing discourage the creator effort if someone simply edits his information?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Are you asking _"how do you get this badge?"_, or _"does this badge discourage the creation of new tag wikis?"_?

Comment: both the question

Comment: You should ask only one question per post.

Comment: You **always should** edit others' post if it significantly improves the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**How to get the badge:**

The [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) explains it:

> First tag wiki edit

It's also mentioned in the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/168333) on Meta Stack Exchange.

You need to edit a tag wiki. Either creating a tag and add its wiki. Or editing an existing tag wiki.

Since you have less than 20.000 reputation points, the tag wiki edit must be Approved. If it is Approved, you will get the badge.
If you have more than 20.000 reputation points, your tag wiki edits won't need peer review.

Note that if your tag wiki edit gets Rejected, you won't get the badge. So try to make your edit a good one!

**Encouraging/Discouraging effects:**

Regarding encouraging/discouraging effects: tag wikis are, well, wikis. They're supposed to be a community effort. So if you see a tag wiki that needs an update, go ahead and make the edit to improve it. That won't discourage other users from creating or editing tags.
If someone creates a tag, and another user gives it a good tag wiki - that will show the creator that more people are interested in that tag. That should be encouraging.

**Warning:**

Before you go out and edit tag wikis... **PLEASE** don't just copy-paste Wikipedia or another website for a tag wiki edit!! There's too much plagiarism going on already in tag wikis. Use your own words and make the edit specific for Stack Overflow.